# How does heuristic work with multiple agents?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

I have a question for heuristic search with multiple agents. I know how heuristic search works with one agent (ex. one Pacman) but I don't really understand it with multiple agents. Let's say we have this problem where Worm A has to get to its goal state A and Worm B to B, knowing that the agents can move only in vertical and horizontal way:
[image: Worm A should get to its goal state A and Worm B to its goal state B]

If we had only Worm B, the optimal cost from starting position to the goal position would be `9`, since one action costs `1` and it'd follow the path `RIGHT-RIGHT-RIGHT-RIGHT-RIGHT-RIGHT-UP-UP-UP`.

My question is, if we have two worms, like in the picture, the optimal cost would be `9 + optimal cost for Worm A`?

Also, strictly for this problem with 2 agents, if we use Manhattan distance as a heuristic for **one agent**, would it be admissible if we take the **average of Worm A and B heuristics** for a problem with **two agents**?

Another question, I know for a fact that **sum of two admissible heuristics** won't be admissible for one agent but would it be for the problem with **two agents**?

**EDIT**: I forgot to add that these two worms are dependent of each other. How? If one worm moves from position X to Y, the position X is marked as a wall and is not an available field to move in. So if one worm has been in a specific position, that position is no more free for moving in.

Comment: What is the dependency between the two agents  ? If none why not apply the same heuristic twice, once for agent a -> A and once for agent b -> B.

Comment: @c0der I just edited. If one worm moves from X to Y, the X position is not available for moving in anymore. So for this strict problem if Worm B gets moving RIGHT, it'll block Worm A and the solution will return None. In this case, Worm B should go DOWN-RIGHT-RIGHT... so the Worm A doesn't get stuck

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask that question

Comment: **<**"_if Worm B gets moving RIGHT, it'll block Worm A and the solution will return None_"  **>**  I disagree. By the time Worm A gets to this point it is likely that Worm B is not there anymore. There is a conflict only when one worm wants to move to a position currently occupied by the other Worm.

Comment: @c0der Incorrect, I wrote that if a worm moves from X to Y, where the Y is the current field and X the previous, X (the previous) becomes not available for moving in. For example, if we had B****||*, where * is an available field and | is a wall, after one RIGHT action, the grid will have the look of |B***||*, after one more RIGHT action, ||B**||*, etc.